# Building Kaltura HTML5 Video Player with AdSupport for VAST/VPAID

Tags: html, html5-video, kaltura, vast

I want to use the Kaltura standalone HTML5 player with the VAST/VPAID ad support modules, but I'm at a loss. I'm not at all familiar with the Kaltura architecture, and thought I've found lots of detail and discussion in the Kaltura support documentation and community forums, I'm not having any luck getting it work. (Ex: http://www.kaltura.org/ad-support-integration)

I've setup the HTML5 player (kaltura-html5player-widget.1.6a_0.zip) in a local environment (running Apache and PHP on Linux), and I've downloaded the AdSupport modules from GitHub (https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed/tree/master/modules/AdSupport), but can't figure out how to load the AdSupport modules for use in the player.

Here's what I have so far, but nothing is loading:

```
<head>
    <title>Simple Video Sample</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <!--  Include jQuery -->        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
    <!-- Include the css and javascript -->
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("../skins/jquery.ui.themes/kaltura-dark/jquery-ui-1.7.2.css");
    </style>  
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("../mwEmbed-player-static.css");
    </style>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../mwEmbed-player-static.js" ></script>

    <script>
    mw.load("modules/AdSupport/resources/mw.AdLoader.js",function(){
       mw.AdLoader.load( 'http://path/to/vast/ad.xml', function( adConf ){
            // Now you can call addAdToPlayerTimeline with the adConf
             mw.addAdToPlayerTimeline( embedPlayer, ['preroll', 'bumper','overlay', 'postroll'], adConf );
       });
    });             
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <h3>Simple video sample</h3>

    <video id="vid1" width="480" height="300" 
    poster="http://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/icann-logo.svg"
    durationHint="33"        
    >
        <source src="http://path/to/video.mp4" type="video/h264" />
    </video>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The kaltura player support VAST/VPAID out of the box both javascript [html5] & flash.
in order to use it please get the latest from our main repository here : https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed

In order to use kaltura player without kaltura backend we develop a proxy layer that will enable you to decide from where do you want to get the video metadata and sources. this layer is still under development/qa but if you want to experience with it :https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed/tree/proxyPlayer

all the player details + API is on player.kaltura.com site.

we also have a nice studio in our KMC(management console) where you can configure your player and take the configuration for your own needs.

let me know if more details is needed.

thanks,

Comment: Could you please provide code example how to use that player, as a standalone with VPAID?

I am trying to run it with Liverail, there is even test Kaltura player on their site: http://test.liverail.com/player/index.php?player=kvpaid&LR_PUBLISHER_ID=51913&LR_TAGS=vpaid&LR_AUTOPLAY=

However I am not going to use Kaltura backend. I've got already own, need to run a player only.

Comment: Hey, I was looking for the same myself and I have setup a demo without the Kaltura backend, displaying a Javascript VPAID non-linear overlay ad. Thought I'd let you know in case it's still of use! :)

Comment: Hey Oli, Could you point me in the right direction to set that up? I am finding it pretty hard to work out how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an answer you are looking for, but it looks like this is impossible without the Kaltura backend:
http://forum.kaltura.org/t/running-kaltura-standalone-player-with-vpaid-support/837

I am chasing the same, trying to find the HTML5 / Flash standalone player with the VPAID support.